# Inserir input somente se ainda não existir

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou trabalhando em um form com campos inseridos dinamicamente. Mas quero que os campos sejam inseridos apenas se não existirem ainda. Meu html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Testando</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Milho <input type="checkbox" class="check"> </p>
    <p>Sorgo <input type="checkbox" class="check"> </p>
    <p>Monenzina <input type="checkbox" class="check"> </p>
    <p>Calcário Calcítico <input type="checkbox" class="check"> </p>
    <p>Farelo de Soja <input type="checkbox" class="check"> </p>
    <p>Farelo de Algodão <input type="checkbox" class="check"> </p>
    <p>Aromatizante <input type="checkbox" class="check"> </p>
    <p>Farelo de Arroz <input type="checkbox" class="check"> </p>

    <button id="add-button" type="submit">Adicionar</button>

    <div id="receiver">
        <form id="form-receiver">
            <fieldset>

            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Meu javascript:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#add-button').click(function(){
        $('.check').each(function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                $('#form-receiver fieldset').append("<p>" +$(this).parent().text()+ "<input name='" + $(this).parent().text().toLowerCase() + "'></p>")
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

Assim a inserção funciona perfeitamente. No entanto, é possível que campos repetidos sejam adicionados caso o usuário decida marcar mais checkboxes e clicar no botão adicionar. Devem ser adicionados somente se não existirem.

Tentei da seguinte forma:

```
$('#add-button').click(function(){
        $('.check').each(function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                if(!$('#form-receiver').has("input[name='" $(this).parent().text().toLowerCase() "']"){
                    $('#form-receiver fieldset').append("<p>" +$(this).parent().text()+ "<input name='" + $(this).parent().text().toLowerCase() + "'></p>")
                }
            }
        })
    });
```

Mas ainda não funcionou. Alguém poderia dar uma ajudinha aqui? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi seu problema da seguinte forma, embora acho que de pra resolver de outra maneira.

Adicionei ao `checkbox` um attibuto `data-add` que irá garantir se o campo foi inserido ou não, ficou desta forma.

***JQuery***

```
$(function(){
    $('#add-button').click(function(){
            $('.check').each(function(){
                if($(this).is(':checked'))
                    if(!$(this).data('add')) {
                        $('#form-receiver fieldset').append("<p>" +$(this).parent().text()+ "<input name='" + $(this).parent().text().toLowerCase() + "'></p>");
                        $(this).attr('data-add', true);
                    }
            });
        });
});
```

Pode acompanhar o resultado nesta **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/Y6R3s/)**

Caso não queira utilizar atributos `data-` pode fazer dessa maneira usando uma variável para controle do mesmo.

```
var checked = [];

$(function(){
    $('#add-button').click(function(){
            $('.check').each(function(index){
                if($(this).is(':checked'))
                    if(!checked[index]) {
                        $('#form-receiver fieldset').append("<p>" +$(this).parent().text()+ "<input name='" + $(this).parent().text().toLowerCase() + "'></p>");
                        checked[index] = true;
                    }
            });
        });
});
```

Pode acompanhar o resultado também nesta ***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/Y6R3s/1/)***

Comment: Cara!! Valeu demais! Não tinha nem cogitado essa possibilidade! Resolveu meu problema. Muito, muito obrigado! ;-)

Comment: Disponha @PedroVinícius implemente também a solução do amigo ali referente aos nomes do campo, um grande abraço e boa sorte com os projetos.

Answer (score 1):

Eu evitaria usar nomes com espaços.
Assim sugiro uma função para fazer CamelCase <sup>[fonte aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10425344/2256325)</sup>:

```
function camelCase(input) {
    return input.toLowerCase().replace(/[-\s](.)/g, function (match, group1) {
        return group1.toUpperCase();
    });
}
```

Depois podia usar este código:

```
$('#add-button').click(function () {
    $('.check').each(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            var nome = $(this).parent().text();
            if (!$('#form-receiver').find("input[name='" + camelCase(nome) + "']").length) {
                $('#form-receiver fieldset').append("<p>" + nome + "<input name='" + camelCase(nome) + "'></p>")
            }
        }
    })
});
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/ULLD9/2/

De qq maneira a unica diferença relevante entre o meu código e o seu é que eu usei
 `if (!$('#form-receiver').find( .... ).length`. O length é só por precaução mas o `find` é para procurar se existe o elemento dentro da form. Mudei também para `this.checked` pois não precisa de jQuery para fazer essa verificação.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Sua resposta foi de grande utilidade! Poderia me explicar o que está acontecendo ali na função replace? Só mesmo pra eu saber exatamente o que estou fazendo e garantir o aprendizado :-)

Comment: @PedroVinícius, a ideia do "Camelize" é remover espaços brancos e fazer a primeira letra de cada palavra ficar em "Capital". Ou seja: `border-width` fica `borderWidth`

Comment: Ahh sim. Obrigado! :D

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade, apesar de já haverem boas resposta, o erro em sua solução e falta de concatenação no seletor de verificação:

```js
// adicionei os operadores de concatenação de string '+'
if(!$('#form-receiver').has("input[name='" + $(this).parent().text().toLowerCase() + "']")
```

E também o método `.has()` do jQuery não retorna um `boolean`, e sim o resultado de uma seleção, então você teria que verificar se retornou alguém no seletor:

```js
$('#form-receiver fieldset').has("input[name='" + $(this).parent().text().toLowerCase().trim() + "']").length == 0
```

E não recomendaria criar `tags` `name` com espaços em branco, eu faria um `trim()`:

```js
$(this).parent().text().toLowerCase().trim();
```

Acompanhe sua solução em funcionamento [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/yp9CZ/3/).

Mas ainda assim recomendo utilizar a solução do [@Diego Vieira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/25328/2998), por ser mais limpa.

Comment: Mas o trim não remove apenas os espaços anteriores e posteriores à string?

Comment: @PedroVinícius, sim, mais havia espaços depois, os do meio nem tava citando, mas também é interessante fazer um `replace` em todos os espaços. Boa colocação.

Comment: Ahh sim. Eu nem tinha notado os espaços depois kkk
Valeu mesmo cara! Sua resposta foi muito útil!